# Connection refused when accessing my website using its domain name but not its IP address (simple nginx setup on digitalocean droplet)

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, networking, dns, installation

I have a rudimentary test/setup site being served via nginx on a Digitalocean droplet running Ubuntu 18.04.

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04) (pretty much verbatim) to setup nginx.

When I enter the IP address of the droplet, I land on the default nginx landing page, as shown in the tutorial link above. However, when I use the domain I have registered with the IP address, I get an `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.`

When I use [this tool site](https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=a%3ajohnmanos.dev&run=toolpage), it shows that my domain is resolving to the correct IP address.

When I run `systemctl status nginx` , it shows that it is active(running). I do not believe the firewall is the issue because running `sudo ufw disable` does not make a difference.

If I run `nping --tcp -p 80 example.com` it successfully pings the IP address / port.

All in all, I am a beginner with this stuff, and I would greatly appreciate any help because I have been trying to solve this for quite some time.

Comment: Have you found a solution ?

Comment: I had a similar problem with a locally hosted service that I could reach using its IP, but not the domain-name, which accurately pointed to the IP. The solution was to explicitly write `https://`, otherwise the address I entered (e.g. `myservice.mylocalnet.myaleveldomain.com`) would resolve to `http://`, which was rejected by the web-server.